# Is there any point in a JS file that has no functions?

Tags: javascript

I've got Olapic's API in front of me, and it looks something like this:

```
<script src="https://olapic_source.net"
        data-olapic="olapic_specific_widget"
        data-instance="213598612346580671235"
        data-apikey="081274081760283650812734612"
        data-tags="product_ID"
        async="async">
</script>
```

I'm all for keeping JS out of HTML files wherever possible. I'm just wondering if there is any reason to put this in its own file, versus putting it right on the page.

The only requirement is that the script is located inside of a div class called "olapic_specific_widget"

So essentially

```
<div class="olapic_specific_widget">
    <script src="path/to/external/file.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</div>
```

Which is tidier than

```
<div class="olapic_specific_widget">
    <script src="https://olapic_source.net"
        data-olapic="olapic_specific_widget"
        data-instance="213598612346580671235"
        data-apikey="081274081760283650812734612"
        data-tags="product_ID"
        async="async">
    </script>
</div>
```

And so again, is there a point to this, or should I just leave all that stuff in there? If there is a point to it, I know you're supposed to take the script tag out of the external file. So, does my external file then look like this?

```
src="https://olapic_source.net"
data-olapic="olapic_specific_widget"
data-instance="213598612346580671235"
data-apikey="081274081760283650812734612"
data-tags="product_ID"
async="async"
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why does `”product_ID”` have the closing quote `”` twice instead of `""`? Also, I wouldn’t publish an API key.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why it was doing that. Thank you. And I agree, I wouldn't publish it either, hence the question, because if I put the above into its own js file, it does nothing. Well that's not true. It dies.

Comment: Depending on the specs of the API, if that's the public half of a public/private keypair putting the key in the source is perfectly fine. As it stands, I don't think you'll be able to put that in its own file. Even if you did, people would still be able to look at that file and see the api key; so I can't imagine that's the private key.

Comment: I thought about that, I could only get the value of a variable, and even then it would appear in the source in one way or another.

Comment: Hi there. It doesn't matter too much, since you decided to delete it, but I noticed you rolled back some community changes on your last question. It's worth bearing in mind that changes added by users are usually useful - you can reject them if they substantially change the nature of the post, however. In this case, I trimmed out chat ("apologies if this is vague") and things that people already know ("I'll add more information as is needed"). We like snappy and succinct here! `:-)` Did you get it sorted out, btw?

Comment: @halfer I appreciate the explanation of the changes, I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks. We ended up just putting the key public, which sucks, but it was the only way to work it with our system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script loaded from the `src` URL probably examines the page and looks for a `<script>` tag inside of a `<div class="olapic_specific_widget">`.

You cannot move any of the `data-` attributes out of the `<script>` tag, because the script loaded from `src` expects the `<script>` DOM element to contain those `data-` attributes. These settings are **HTML attributes**, not JavaScript.

In short, this `<script>` tag acts in two different roles at one:

1. a mechanism to import a remote script (because it has a `src` attribute)
2. a collection of widget settings, specified by `data-` attributes.

The remote script (that is imported by the `<script>` in role #1) reads the data that is set in the `<script>`'s attributes (in role #2).

Comment: This is everything I needed to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this way to use the `<script>` element as a kind of *remote function call*. The several `data` attributes are the parameters of the call, and the script itself, as specified with the `src` URL, can perform a variety of actions depending on these parameters. This adds more flexibility in the design of JavaScript libraries for use in web pages.